# How to change datepicker date format?

Tags: javascript, xul

By default, the [datepicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/datepicker)'s format is MM/DD/YYYY, I would like it to be DD/MM/YYYY, is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-dateFormat

Comment: `.selector` refers to what? It had no effect when I add `$(".selector").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });` to my script. Also, what I'm looking for is the datepicker to show the format DD/MM/YYYY, not just to get this format when I read the datepicker..

Comment: selector is how you identify your particular picker...so perhaps instead of `.selector`, you'd have `#myDatePickerID` or `.myDatePickerClass`

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change your locale settings to DD/MM/YYYY, you could try subclassing the datepicker binding and overriding the `_init` method. You need to set the following properties:

```
this._separatorFirst.value = '/';
this._separatorSecond.value = '/';
this.dayField = document.getAnonymousElementByAttribute(this, "anonid", "input-one");
this.monthField = document.getAnonymousElementByAttribute(this, "anonid", "input-two");
this.yearField = document.getAnonymousElementByAttribute(this, "anonid", "input-three");
this.yearField.parentNode.className = "datetimepicker-input-subbox datetimepicker-year";
this.yearField.size = 4;
this.yearField.maxLength = 4;
this.yearLeadingZero = true;
this.monthLeadingZero = true;
this.dayLeadingZero = true;
this._fieldAMPM.parentNode.collapsed = true;
```

Also consider filing an enhancement request to override the format with an attribute and/or property.